# how to customize the scroll bar as per the screen shot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

[image]

Have a look at the screen sort ,this scroll bar is different from the general one,till time what ever i have worked with the scroll bar ,the text level and scroll bar level finish at the same level,but in this case ,the scroll bar is elongated one.I have tried putting `padding bottom:xpx`.(x =tried with multiple values),but it does not work.In the page the text is put inside a div and the rhombus are build in canvas(different div) How can I lengthen my scroll bar length more than the text level?

Comment: If only we had the code to check.

Comment: joseph  in the picture the last text visible is "Electrical system" but the length of the scroll bar touches the mid of rhombus,what ever i have tried earlier the text and scroll bar level finish at the same level ,which is not the case here ,the scroll bar is lengthier one ,that is what i want to achieve

Comment: if u want i can put the code ,but it has nothing special, it contains a div having some text ,and the rhombus drawn in canvas(which is independent of the div)

Comment: @N.Nihar You can try to style the general scroll bar using CSS3 without making another one. Here is a reference link: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/. Or put your code here, so we can see what's going wrong there.

Comment: i beleive the webkit- scroll bar thing may not wok in IE ,if it is so , i can not take risk doing that

Comment: Please check below link. http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lot of different jQuery plugins.

This one is one of my fave. http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/